# Keyboard not appearing when tap on login dialog boxes of Facebook login view in Facebook like Delegate

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, xcode, xcode4.2

I am using facebook like delegate in my iphone app and when facebook login page pop ups, and i tap on username or password field, keyboard does not appear. Can anyone tell why this happens?

Comment: I have used that delegte in my another app and it is working fine... but in another one the keyboard is not appearing :(

Answer (score 0):

Try to make sure that your boolean value for your delegate is not overriding the keyboard appearing.  Try looking for the resignFirstResponder method and changing the return value to see if that has an effect.